# Rails 3 render problems

Tags: yaml, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a script that allows for a user to pass a format via a URL parameter. I have JSON and XML working as needed, but I can't get YAML working.

```
case params[:format]
        when "xml" then respond_with(@labels)
        when "json" then respond_with(@labels_hash.to_json)
        when "yaml" then render :text => @labels_hash.to_yaml
      end
```

For some reason when I pass the `format=yaml` in my URL then my script tries to force download a file. Any reason why this would happen?

Working Code:

```
case params[:format]
        when "xml" then respond_with(@labels)
        when "json" then respond_with(@labels_hash.to_json)
        when "yaml" then respond_with(@labels_hash) do |format|
          format.yaml { render :text => @labels_hash.to_s }
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Adding `:yaml` to `respond_to :yaml` in the controller, and :

```
respond_to do |format|
  ....other formats....
  format.yaml { render :yaml => @labels_hash }
end
```

Comment: I tried that but it still is trying to force download a file.

Comment: I got it working using a cURL call. I was trying to view the created YAML in a browser and didn't think that the browser isn't going to know how to interpret a YAML MIME Type